# How to transform response from API request into class instance with `class-transformer` in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, transformation, class-transformer

I have normal method `Request(method: HttpMethod, url: string, ...)` for calling API. I am using TypeScript.

I need to transform response from this API Request into class instance with `class-transformer` (or without it :D).

Example:

```js
class UserResponse {
  id: number;l
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}
const user = await Request(HttpMEthod.GET, '/user/1');
// `user` should be class instance `UserResponse`
```

I know I cannot use generics like so:

```
const Request = <T>(method: HttpMethod, url: string, ...) => {
  // axios or something else...
  return plainToClass(T, res);
}

const user = await Request<UserResponse>(HttpMEthod.GET, '/user/1');
```

Generics do not work that way, but I can do something like:

```
const Request = <T>(method: HttpMethod, url: string, ...,  transformTo?: { new (): T }) => {
  // axios or something else...
  return plainToClass(transformTo, res);
}

const user = await Request(HttpMEthod.GET, '/user/1', ... , new UserResponse());
```

But this also not working. I am still getting `user` type:

```
const user: unknown
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, what is `Request`? I am assuming this returns a `Promise`.

You have a couple of issues:

1. You never actually map your response into a `new UserResponse`
2. Generics in TypeScript will not *new up* a response. It acts more like an `interface` where it's more a data contract rather than a full initialized class.

Here is how you need to do this:

```js
class UserResponse {
  public id: number;
  public foo: string;
  public bar: string;
  constructor(user: UserResponse) {
    Object.assign(this, user); // or set each prop individually
  }
}
const response = await Request(HttpMEthod.GET, '/user/1');
const user = new UserResponse(response);
```

Basically, you need to add a `constructor` to your class (otherwise, just use an `interface`). Once you've got the `constructor`, then you can *new up* a new `UserResponse` class from the response.

Also, if `Request` looks like:

```
const Request = <T>(method: HttpMethod, url: string, ...,  transformTo?: { new (): T }) => {
  // axios or something else...
  return plainToClass(transformTo, res);
}
```

I think you want to do this instead:
`const user = await Request(HttpMEthod.GET, '/user/1', ... , UserResponse);`

Comment: I have problem that my `UserReponse` is type of `any`... Why classes do not have automatically own type?

Comment: `UserResponse` is not type `any`. It's `UserResponse`

Comment: Thats the problem.. It is not in my code... Or WebStorm IDE thinks its `any`

Comment: `UserResponse` is imported from shared library (custom npm package) which is built to .js + d.ts

Comment: I had bug when I was compiling this shared library... Its fine now. Thanks :)